# Determining Point given two other points and headings

Tags: javascript, coordinates, latitude-longitude, intersection

I'm working on a project that has radio receivers in various points. When these receivers receive a signal, they output their location and the heading towards that signal in the form:

```
{
  "current": [
    {
      "heading": 292.5, 
      "id": 1, 
      "lat": 43.08429, 
      "lon": -77.674126, 
      "name": "node1"
    }, 
    {
      "heading": 90, 
      "id": 2, 
      "lat": 43.084537, 
      "lon": -77.681288, 
      "name": "node2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to take this information and find the latitude and longitude of the signal.

The way I've been thinking of handling this is finding the equations of the lines that contain possible lat and lons from each node. Then, I can find where these lines intersect.  While this is great in theory, I'm finding it a bit difficult to implement.

I'm assuming that 0 degrees is North. In the example above, finding the equation of the line for `node2` is easy, since it's just a line pointing East,  `y = -77.681288`.

For `node1` it's a bit trickier, especially to code.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the position (latitude) and the distances involved, I think that a plane could be a good (local) approximation of earth surface nearby the receivers.

The parametric equation of a line (ray) passing from a known point with a known slope (heading) is:

*x = x<sub>0</sub> + t cosα*
*y = y<sub>0</sub> + t sinα*

The angle should be measured in radians, so to transform from heading (0° is North) to radians ( 0 is East):

```
function heading_to_radians() {
    var angle = 90.0 - heading;
    if ( angle < -180.0 ) angle = angle + 360.0;
    if ( angle > 180.0 ) angle = angle - 360.0;
    return angle * Math.PI / 180.0;
}
```

The intersection between the two lines can be find with:

```
var alpha = heading_to_radians(heading1),
    ca = Math.cos(alpha),
    sa = Math.sin(alpha),
    beta = heading_to_radians(heading2),
    cb = Math.cos(beta),
    sb = Math.sin(beta),
    dx = longitude2 - longitude1,
    dy = latitude2 - latitude1,
    t, k, den, longitude3, latitude3;
if ( ca > 0.01  ||  ca < -0.01 ) {
    k = sa / ca;
    den = cb * k - sb;
    t = ( dy - dx * k) / den;
} else {
    k = ca / sa;
    den = sb * k - cb;
    t = ( dx - dy * k) / den;
}
longitude3 = longitude2 + t * cb;
latitude3 = latitude2 + t * sb;
```

With your example data the result is Longitude -77.67472231 and Latitude 43.084537 or according to GoogleMaps:

[image]

For longer distances or higher latitudes you should use some better approximations, like the formulas you can find [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).